# VueJS vue@3.4.8 Component v-model does not update parent initially

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a parent child component setup to test v-model. The child updates parent when you enter a value but not initially.

parent:

```
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue';

import TextInput from './TextInput.vue';

const size = ref(1);
const color = ref('red');
</script>

<template>

  <TextInput v-model:size="size" v-model:color.capitalize="color" />
  <div :style="{ fontSize: size + 'em', color: color }">
    <!-- Question 1: this line shows "red" but "Red" is what I want initially -->
    <p>{{ size }} {{ color }}</p>
  </div>

</template>
```

child: TextInput.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const size = defineModel('size');

const [color, modifier] = defineModel('color', {
  set(value) {
    if(modifier.capitalize) {
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    }
    return value;
  },
  //only this forces color to upper case on start in the input
  get(value) {
    if(modifier.capitalize) {
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    }
    return value;
  }
});

</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="size">
  <input v-model="color">
</template>
```

Question 2:
If I omit "color" in  defineModel("color", {..., I get the following error

[Vue warn]: Extraneous non-props attributes (color, colorModifiers) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes.

```
at <TextInput size=1 onUpdate:size=fn color="red"  ... > 
at <ComponentVModel> 
at <App>
```

If I keep just the

```
<input v-model="color">
```

line, to make it not a fragment, it doesn't update at all.

Comment: seems odd but yeah it definitely behaves that way - it seems `onMounted(() => { color.value = color.value; })` hacks it to be right!

Comment: Yes. That does it.  Not only that with that fix I could do away with the get(value) lines to make it appear upper case in the input field initialy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: the capitalization within the `<p>` element won't happen until the v-model setter in the child is called. **The setter is the one that syncs back to the parent**. Since the setter is not called until the input receives some text from the user, the `<p>` element in the parent will display the initial value, in your case "red".

Question 2: defineModel declares a prop based on the first argument string, 'color'. This prop is designed to match the argument of the **v-model on the parent**, i.e. `v-model:color`. Removing 'color' from defineModel means the parent v-model must be changed from `v-model:color` to just `v-model`

Comment: The setter is not called and so no case conversion occurs. okay. I thought the setter will act in an eager fashion and apply the conversion. Q2. I removed the :color and it worked.  Having defineModel("color", { ... helps in having more properties like this I guess. The example on the Vue page https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html has only one property so there was no need to specify "color".